# Solving a differential equation with NDSolve and plotting it WITH the use of Manipulate

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve, let's say, this differential equation:

```
y'[x]=y[x]^n
```

Given any initial condition (which I might want to manipulate too).

I want to plot the graph of this function while manipulating the exponential factor `n`. I tried something like this:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^n, y[0] == 0}, y[x], x]; 
Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -5, 5}], {n, 0, 2}]
```

But it does not work...

I'm really sorry, but I'm new to *Mathematica* so it can be a really simple thing. Already grateful for the help!

Answer (score 5):

```
Manipulate[ Plot[y[x] /. sol[n], {x, 0, 2}, Evaluated -> True],
 {n, 0, 4},
 Initialization-> {sol@h_:= Quiet@NDSolve[{y'@x == y@x^h, y@0 == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun and using `DynamicModule` and only looking at integer exponents:

```
DynamicModule[{p},
 Framed[Column[{
    Dynamic[With[{h = p},
      sol = 
       First@Quiet[
         DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^h, y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 2}]];
      Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 2}, Evaluated -> True, 
       PlotStyle -> Red, 
       Epilog -> Text[Style[y[x] /. sol, White], Center], 
       Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> White, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
       ImageSize -> 350]]],
    Row[{Style["Exponent", White, Bold], Spacer[20], 
      SetterBar[Dynamic[p], Range[0, 10]]}]}], RoundingRadius -> 20, 
  Background -> Black]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. There are two things. One is to make the NDSolve syntax correctly. That is to give `{x,0,5}`instead of simply `x`in it, since NDSolve is a numeric solution and one needs to fix the limits for the variables.

The second is to put the solution of the equation under the `Manipulate` statement. Otherwise the solution will "not be aware" of your varying the n value:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^n, y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 5}];
 Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 5}],
   {n, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for clear answer as always. In case you find the time, your input on this recent post would be very valuable https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166671/taking-log-derivatives-of-data-in-mathematica Look forward to hearing from you. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @ user929304 Have a look into the question you mentioned above, I gave an answer.