# Plotting the solution to a differential equation with a varying parameter

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I have the differential equation

$\qquad x'' + 4 x' + 148x = 37 \sin(Ω\,t)$

with initial conditions

$\qquad x(0) = 1,\ x'(0) = 0$

I would like to plot it in a `Manipulate` expression to vary the value of the parameter $Ω$. How do I do this?

Comment: Please write your ODE in Mathematica format and briefly show what you have done so far.

Comment: Also, this ODE can be solved symbolically with `Flatten@DSolve[{x''[t] + 4 x'[t] + 148 x[t] == 37 Sin[w t], x[0] == 1,  x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t] // Simplify`

Comment: I have managed to solve the ODE to get x[t] -> 1/
  24 E^(-2 t) (24 Cos[12 t] + 4 Sin[12 t] + 
    6 E^(2 t) Sin[Ωt] - 
    6 Cos[12 t] Sin[Ωt] - 
    Sin[12 t] Sin[Ωt]   But i wish to put this into a plot where i can vary the parameter Ω

Comment: Use `Manipulate`.  But first, check the answer in your last comment, which does not agree with the `DSolve` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the asked solution, but before to ask, make a search on the question and try to learn a little of the syntax of MA. This question is a duplicate Look at [Solving a differential equation with NDSolve and plotting it WITH the use of Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64032/solving-a-differential-equation-with-ndsolve-and-plotting-it-with-the-use-of-man)

```
Manipulate[
 s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 4 x'[t] + 148 x[t] == 
     37 Sin[Ω t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 30}];
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {Ω, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you very much.