# Taking log derivatives of data in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, logarithmic-scale

We have two lists (vectors) of data, y and x, we can imagine x being time steps (0,1,2,...) and y some system property computed at each value of x. I'm interested in calculating the derivative of log of y with respect to log of x, and the question is how can I preform such calculations in Mathematica? We first go to log space, e.g. `logx = Map[Log,x]` similarly for `y.` Then what method do we use for the differentiation dlog(y)/dlog(x)? and then eventually we'll plot it as a function of `log(x).`

**Context:**
When we have a quantity `y` for which we expect to see a power law behaviour as a function of `x,` so $y \propto x^{\alpha},$ taking the log derivative of y w.r.t to x allows us to extract the actual $\alpha$ corresponding to our data.

Comment: Could interpolate in log-log space and take derivatives of the interpolated form. This needs to be done with a reasonable interpolation degree so as not to introduce artificial wiggles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, I like most of all the approach proposed by @Daniel Lichtblau as a comment. I would propose Daniel to formulate it as a regular answer.

If the data is noisy, the interpolation can give rise to problems, since it goes through all points. The function, thus, strongly oscillates, and its derivatives can appear unnecessarily large and also noisy.

Instead, the strategy using fitting may be a good idea to apply, if the noise is present. The latter enables one to create a smooth, slowly varying function, thus effectivey reducing the effect of the noise in the derivative. Here I would like to propose a simple idea of how to treat the problem by the fitting. Since the author gave no list, to be able to show code, I will create such a list. Since the author is primarily interested in a power law-type of dependence, this will be the cases of the lists below.

The first example is a simple power law to which I add a bit of noise:

```
lst1 = Table[{x, x^(3/2) + RandomReal[{-30, 30}]}, {x, 1, 100}];
ListPlot[lst1]
```

yielding this:

[image]

This list can be transformed into a Log-Log list:

```
lst1Log = lst1 /. {x_, y_} -> {Log[x], Log[y]} // N;
```

The next step is to fit it to a suitable function. In principle, by looking at its plot one can easily guess that at large values of `t=Log[x]` it has a linear asymptote. This agrees with the author's expectation of a power law. It is not astonishing, since I created this list to be such. However, the authors expectation and the form of the plot gives me a hint to fit it to a linear function:

```
     model1 = a + b*t;
ff1 = FindFit[Select[lst1Log, #[[1]] > 3 &], model1, {a, b}, t]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst1Log, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[model1 /. ff1, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
    (*   {a -> 0.167, b -> 1.46}   *)
```

where `a` and `b` are the fitting parameters, `b`being the exponent of the power law. The result differs from the power law `b=1.5` since it is influenced by stattered points at small `t`. To improve it one can cut away the list points at smaller `t`: `Select[lst1Log, #[[1]] > 4 &]` and make a fit starting from the value `b=1.46` obtained within the previous step:

model1 = a + b*t;
ff1 = FindFit[Select[lst1Log, #[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnaFM.jpg)] > 4 &], model1, {a, {b, 1.46}}, t]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst1Log, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[model1 /. ff1, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]

(*   {a -> -0.0245, b -> 1.51}  *)

Here how it looks like:

[image]

The difference from 1.5 is due to the noise.

The second example is the list containing two power laws and exhibiting a slightly more complex dependence:

```
    lst2 = Table[{x, 5 x^(1/2) + 0.001*x^2.7 + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {x,
         4, 1000}];
    lst2Log = lst2 /. {x_, y_} -> {Log[x], Log[y]} // N; 
ListPlot[lst2]
```

[image]

It is the same story, but looking at the plot of the Log-Log list (that is, lst2Log) one can guess that it can be fitted by a slightly different function:

```
model2 = (a + b*t^(d + 1))/(1 + c*t^d)
```

Here `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are parameters. In such functions, however, the exponents (such as `d`) are usually difficult to fit. For this reason instead of the fitting it is convenient to manipulate with the parameter `d`while fitting all the rest:

```
Manipulate[
 model2 = (a + b*t^(d + 1))/(1 + c*t^d);
 ff2 = FindFit[lst2Log, model2, {{a, 3}, b, c}, t];
 Show[{
   ListPlot[lst2Log, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.008]}],
   Plot[model2 /. ff2, {t, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> Red]
   }], 
{{d, 3.58}, 2, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

By manipulating I found that the value `d=3.58` gives a good approximation. It is this value that I placed as an initial one for convenience. This is what you should see on the screen:

[image]

Now one can get the approximation more precisely, by using the values of the parameters obtained in the previous step as their initial values:

```
model2 = (a + b*t^(4.6 + eps))/(1 + c*t^(3.6 + eps));
ff2 = FindFit[Select[lst2Log, #[[1]] > 3.5 &], 
  model2, {{a, 2.55}, {b, 0.007}, {c, 0.003}, {eps, 0.2}}, t]
Show[{
  ListPlot[Select[lst2Log, #[[1]] > 3.5 &], 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.008]}],
  Plot[model2 /. ff2, {t, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]

(*  {a -> 2.72, b -> 0.00462, c -> 0.00228, eps -> 0.258}  *)
```

[image]

The exponent in infinity will in this case be `b/c`. However you can here find the exponent value in each point by calculating the derivative of the `model2`in the desired point.

Generally, in this approach the fitting gives you a simple smooth approximation of the desired function, the derivative of which you can further find.

Have fun!

**Edit 1:** To illustrate how to find the regimes. Within the example 2 you can define the derivative of `y`denoted below as `der[t]` and plot it:

```
Clear[der];
der[t_] := Evaluate[D[model2 /. ff2, t] // Simplify];

Plot[der[t], {t, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["t=Log[x]", Italic, 12], 
   Style["der=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(dLog[y]\), \(dt\)]\)", Italic, 12]}]
```

Here you will find 3 regimes, from 1 to several decades each. In the middle a regime with a derivative described by an almost straight tilted line is visible. It is flanked by two power law rerimes at small and large t values.

**Edit 2**: To address your question with your list.

In this case I would do as follows. Here is your list, that should be somehow downloaded

```
lst = Drop[
Import[FullPathToYourList, "Table"], 1] ;
```

I have dropped the first element of the list, since there is something strange in it. But it makes a negligible influence on the result. 
and 
    lst1=lst/. {x_, y_} -> {Log[x], Log[y]}
Now, looking at the `ListPlot[lst1]` one sees that it consists of two straight regions corresponding to two different regimes (i) at `Log[x]<4` and (ii) at `Log[x]>4`. In principle this means that you could express it in the form of a formula 
y=a e^{-\frac{x}{d}} x^{\alpha }+b \left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{d}}\right)
   x^{\beta }
(I hope that the TeX expression here works). Here  `d` is a cut-off close to 10^4. However, it is not easy to fit such a formula and to do it on the huge interval that takes place here.

For this reason it is more easy to fit the log-log list `lst1`, and to do it for `t=Log[x]<4`´separately from that for `t>4`. Below I do it:

```
   model1 = a + b*x;
model2 = c + k*x;

ff1 = FindFit[Select[lst, #[[1]] < 4 &], model1, {a, b}, x]
ff2 = FindFit[Select[lst, #[[1]] > 10 &], model2, {c, k}, x]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["t=Log[x]", 12, Italic], 
     Style["Log[y]", 12, Italic]}],
  Plot[model1 /. ff1, {x, 1, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[model2 /. ff2, {x, 4, 14}, PlotStyle -> Green]
  }]

(*  {a -> 1.54653449015407020, b -> 0.760890314643084274}

{c -> 3.002027525233422865, k -> 0.3272780474976788419}   *)
```

On the screen you will see the following plot:

[image]

Now, the fitting parameters `b` and `k` above are the exponents you are looking for. So I would say that the exponents are 0.76 and 0.33.

Pay attention that in the ff2 I fit the part of the list with `t>10`. It is because the interval `4<t<10` looks as a transition part of the curve. It is for this reason the solid green line deviates from the blue points in this interval. This is, however, up to you to choose how  and where it is better to fit. It strongly depends on the nature of the problem.

Have fun!

Comment: @user929304 The answer is "yes". This is exactly the second example in my answer. If you can find there two different regions covering not less than a decade along `t` each, such that within each such a region you can accurately approximate the list by a straight line, you get different regimes of your system. This is easy to see by taking `D[model2 /. ff2, t]` and plotting it. Please have a look at the edit

Comment: @user929304 The best would be, if you have a theory describing these different regimes. I think to have dealt with such a situation. You may have a look into papers Uhde et al. Phys. Rev. E 72, 061916 (2005); Uhde et al. Phys. Rev. Lett. 94, 198102 (2005); Ter-Oganessian et al.  Phys. Rev. E 72, 041510 (2005)  and Ter-Oganessian et al. Phys. Rev. E 72, 041511 (2005). There we also faced with a situations with three different power law regimes and the necessity to fit them all. But there the theory has been first created.

Comment: I'm playing catch-up this week so probably won't have time to try code for this. Wanted to mention that a related possibility is to use a smoothing filter as preprocessor. It would be in conjunction with the various other tactics under consideration, not a replacement for them.

Comment: @user929304 Please have a look at the last edit.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thank you very much, this has been incredibly instructive!

Comment: @user929304 This depends on the answer, what would you like to put as the error bar. In general, the plots with the error bars can be done. Have a look at Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/ErrorListPlot. On the other hand, you might want to show residuals. In that case, it may be convenient to use NonlinearModelFit instead of a less powerful FindFit Please have a look.

Comment: @user929304 There are many textbooks on piezo-electric phenomena. The choice depends primarily on your specific problem and also on your background. The first thing I would anyway do, is to look up in Wikipedia. Then I would search for some texts in the web, such that the texts are on the students level. There are also books. If you write a bit in more details about your problem and your background (physicist? mechanicist? engineer? somebody else?) I might give a better advice.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thanks for your reply. Some background: I am physics student and the project is about devising theory for a system of polymer melt (which are stretched) contained in a box, where then the average distance between the chains is large but upon compression of the box, the distance gets smaller and eventually they are close enough to conduct electricity. So the system responded to deformation by gaining conductivity. I am trying to learn how theoretically I can model and link these different properties of system (namely shape, size, average distance, to conductivity). Thanks again

Comment: @user929304 OK, I understand. First, polymers do not conduct, if they are not, so-called, conjugated polymers. So, you either have the conjugated ones in mind, or you have a kind of a mixture of polymers with some conducting objects (such as metallic or semiconducting particles). In the both cases it seems that this is not related to piezoelectricity. It is rather the "percolation theory" that should help you to describe this situation.

Comment: @user929304 Continuation: There are many books on this subject, and you may search for any of them written on your mother language. However, if this area is completely new for you I recommend a book of Shklovsky and Efros "Physics and geometry of disorder" freely available here: https://archive.org/details/physics-of-disorder It is originally written for school-children. So it is exceptionally easy to read. On the other hand, it discusses almost all most important problems of this area. On the basis of this book you may be will then want to read something more specific.

Comment: @user929304 Continuation:  It may, however, be that this single book will be enough. Now, how the percolation theory is related to your problem, as I understood it from your explanation. You have mechanical properties of your polymer (solution? dry state? gel?). This can be expressed by mechanical equations. Have a look at the book Grossberg and Khokhlov "Stytistical physics of a macromolecule" Chapter 5, §29.

Comment: @user929304 Continuation: This book is available in English. Form the mechanical part of the problem you get x, the volume fraction of the conducting agent (say, particles). You then take the conductivity, sigma=sigma(x) form the percolation theory which is known and insert there x obtained from the mechanical problem. Done. Roughly it can be solved like this, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Continuation: of the particles), how does percolation come into play? I mean, I didn't know sigma (conductivity) is well understood within percolation phenomena, i.e. for disordered 3D systems, do you happen to know of relevant references for this? Could it be published under different keywords? I wish there was alternative way we could chat about this. Your comments have already been tremendously helpful.

Comment: user929304 I think it is better to continue this discussion privately, the more that it is not related to Mathematica. you may write me to abo@iee.lu and I will answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

While it seems unlikely that this is what you will actually want, it is what you asked for:

```
xs = Range[100]
ys = 3*xs^0.5
Differences[Log@ys]/Differences[Log@xs]
```

Note that you cannot have a zero value in `xs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is definitely very close, I wonder, is there more accurate ways of performing the numerical differentiation? (for instance higher order differences). Additionally, when taking the `Differences`, the resulting list has one element less than the involved lists (`xs` e.g.,) so for plotting one element from `xs` has to be removed.

Comment: Under your specification, the relationship is loglinear, so in this case no, there is no more accurate method.  In other circumstances, you might average forward and backwards differences or fit a parameterized function and use its derivatives.